# How can I standardize user-entered data?

Tags: database, user-input

I have a table of data that I'm trying to "standardize". The data entered into the table wasn't static or standardized (like with drop-down lists of answers), leaving me with multiple variations of answers where I want a static, universal answer.

For instance, let's say that there's a column in the database called "Type of pet". Because user input wasn't standardized, people could enter in variations of a specific type of pet, rather than generalized form of the pet. So instead of just entering "Dog", there are different versions of dogs like "Collie", "Mutt", "Labrador", etc.

How do I go about transcribing these answers into their generalized form -- replacing Collie/Mutt/Labrador/etc answers in the table with just "Dog" (or "Cat", or "Bird", etc.)?

I realize there needs to be some form of a manually-entered "translation" function. My gut reaction is that a long-spanning list of stacked if-statements would be inefficient, as well as being tedious to control and expand.

Is there some kind of process or system for doing something like this? Like some type of lookup table system/matrix?

I'm assuming a foreach loop to iterate through the array of records would be most appropriate. And then within each iteration of the foreach loop, you'd have it do a test/comparison of the pet variable against some type of list (that I would have created manually) -- but what would you use for this lookup table/list? Or this step of the process? Would you have it as some type of a SQL database/table, an array, a CSV file, etc.?

Then, once this comparison is completed and the "translated" equivalent of the type of pet is determined, the foreach loop would update that specific row of the record, either overwriting the old non-standardized value, or perhaps just tacking on the new standardized equivalent into a new column (for later verifying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My gut reaction is that a long-spanning list of stacked if-statements
>   would be inefficient, as well as being tedious to control and expand.

100% correct, and because of this you really only have one option: Manually go through the database and clean it up. Once that is done you will need to restrict user input using stop down lists rather than raw text input.

Depending on your users you might want to look at how Stackoverflow does tags - essentially allowing anyone to do the cleanup for you.

Comment: How about creating some type of comparison list/table/array/etc that could handle the bulk of the data? (While realizing that I'll definitely have to manually clean up records at some point, like the oddities or rare breeds of dogs whose names weren't included in the comparison table/function)

Comment: My advice would be that if you have decided that this has to be cleaned up, it is better to do it now before it gets any larger or harder to do. Even you create a comparison list, you will still be spending a lot of time on it and going through each entry individually. Why not just do what really needs to be done now?

Comment: I completely agree -- there is no more data that's coming in as dynamic. But with the thousands and thousands of records already in the database, it would take me much longer to do it all manually, vs. a simple type of automated conversion that can handle the bulk of the conversions. And then, of course, I would filter out the flagged stragglers that didn't get processed with the comparison function and either drop them (non vital data) or fix them individually.

Comment: I'm just hung up on what one might use in this case as the comparison list, or lookup table. My limited program experience leads me to make separate variables or arrays of the various specific names for each type of pet category, but my gut feeling is that this could be done more efficiently with some type of SQL table system. One would be able to easily view and edit the list table data to append (or remove) specific animal names, providing an easy way to manage it. But I'm only seeing the general idea of something like that, and now how one might implement it.

Answer (score 0):

But if you have like 150000 records or something  doing an SQL find-replace query might help clean up the data to start.

This sounds like a data normalization project to me though  I don't have alot of experience with it in practice, but in theory you start with how the data is entered.  For instance, free text fields allow users to enter anything they want.  You'd want to change that after scrubbing the data.  And it pays to know how the data got in in the first place.  Was it freetext, a bullet, a drop-down menu?  etc.

You'd also want to create a data dictionary of all the standardized terms that can replace the multitude of variations with.
Then you could create an update query that would go through the old data and update it with the new using an update query and wildcards.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Find-and-Replace-dialog-box-to-change-data-2eee8d02-5a40-4328-ba56-ec0406865680

This could be a more automated way of scrubbing the data rather than find and replace too.

-Al